# Trying to assign value to array elements and return it in another class to work with but not working

Tags: java, arrays

I am having diffculty with trying to assign value to array elements based on a userinput and checking the array element's value in another class. When I do that I get null and I am not sure why and how to fix it.

I have no expereince with java, just started learning it and doing it as part of uni course.

Any help is appreciated and thank you.

Class 1

```
  public class ErrorHandling {
        String[] errorMessage = new String[4];

        public void inputCheck() {

            UserInterface input = new UserInterface();

            int[] checkUserInput = input.getInput();

            if (checkUserInput[0] < 20 || checkUserInput[0] > 80) {

                errorMessage[0] = "Hello";

            }

            if (!(checkUserInput[1] <= 10 && checkUserInput[1] % 2 == 0)) {

                errorMessage[2] = "Hey";
            }

        }

        public String[] getError() {
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Class 2

```
public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInterface input = new UserInterface();

        input.askZigZag();

        ErrorHandling checkError = new ErrorHandling();

        String check[] = checkError.getError();

     if (check[0] == ("Hello")) {
         System.out.println("yh");
     }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please complete the code you have posted; for example, what does `askZigZag` do?  And can you provide *any* details as to the error(s) you are getting (beyond that you "get null")?

Comment: askZigZag gets the users input and stores it in an array. it also contains the Ui which is made up of JoptionsPane.  

I am trying to check if the value of the elements in the array are equal to a value and trying to print a text just to see if it's working but I am getting no results.

I also tried printing the value of the array however when  I do that it just prints null.

Comment: The code isn't calling `inputCheck()` which is the only place that values are written to the `errorMessage` array.

Comment: I added that line of code but still no results

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing your method calls a bit. In class 2, you have a line:

```
String check[] = input.getError();
```

That should probably be:

```
String check[] = checkError.getError();
```

As the `getError()` method is in your first class (ErrorHandling) and not the `UserInterface` class.

Also, you assign `Hello` to `errorMessage[0]` and not `hey`, so that might be failing in your last few lines in class 2.

If you're just starting out with Java I recommend reading up on [Class Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) to understand this (as well as [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)).

**EDIT

String comparison in Java doesn't work using the `==` operator. As they are objects and not primitive data types, you must use `.equals`.

```
check[0].equals("Hello")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I made the changes you stated and still getting nothing.

Comment: Hold up I missed that you're doing string comparison with the equals operator. I'll update my answer, hold on a sec.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:19)
I am getting this error now. However I did test with == operator on another array and it did work as excepted.

Comment: We're getting somewhere! At this point it is properly comparing the value in `check[0]` but `check[0]` is not set. When you use the array constructor `new String[4]` it initializes all positions to null, so unless you set them they will remain that way. Therefore were not getting to the line that sets errorMessage[0], so see if you can figure out why your not getting through that if statement.

Comment: Also you got rid of the call to `inputCheck()`, that was sorta important

Comment: Yep no idea what is wrong. tried everything I know and searched up online.

Comment: I foung the issue, int[] checkUserInput = input.getInput(); in the error handling class isn't gettign the value and assigning it to the array. I tested by assigning values manually to thecheckUserInput array and it functions. But idk why the values are not being assigned when it should.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `checkError.inputCheck()` in the main program otherwise `errorMessage` will not get initialized.

Some tweaks in your code that will help to execute:

Class 1

```
  public class ErrorHandling {
        String[] errorMessage = new String[4];

        public void inputCheck() {

            UserInterface input = new UserInterface();

            int[] checkUserInput = input.getInput();
            // If you want to use askZigZag... use it somewhere inside this function
            // since you have already declared the object of UserInterface.

            if (checkUserInput[0] < 20 || checkUserInput[0] > 80) {

                errorMessage[0] = "Hello";

            }

            if (!(checkUserInput[1] <= 10 && checkUserInput[1] % 2 == 0)) {

                errorMessage[2] = "Hey";
            }

        }

        public String[] getError() {
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Class 2

```
    public class MainProgram {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

          //  UserInterface input = new UserInterface();

          //  input.askZigZag();

            ErrorHandling checkError = new ErrorHandling();
            checkError.inputCheck();
            String check[] = checkError.getError();

         if (check[0].equals("Hello")) {
             System.out.println("yh");
         }
        }

}
```